# Windows Phone Emulator 8 can't install Xamarin application

Tags: windows-phone-8, xamarin

I have created a Xamarin application and compiled to Release. It was succesfully tested on an Android emulator so I decided to deploy it to a Windows Phone 8.0 Emulator.

I tried to use the Application Deployment but it cannot install because it starts the emulator that never boots, it shows OS starting (starting the emulator on its own is working).

So I downloaded it to the phone and when I try to open it, it says:

> Can't install company app. There is a problem with this company app.
>   Contact your company's support person for help.

Why is the app considered company app? How can I install it to the emulator? What should I set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution consists of two steps.

The *company app issue* is present because I've downloaded the application from a website, so it is unsafe (the source is the Internet). I have to install it ***through application deployment (via Visual Studio 2013 or the Windows Phone Application Deployment application).***

The second step is to ***discard (and uninstall) Windows Phone 8.0*** and change to *Windows Phone 8.1.* That helps a lot.